# Flutter Layout issues

Tags: flutter, grid, row

I am having trouble laying out my buttons.

I basically want a gridview that expands each child to be the height of the largest child. For example:

[image]

I have tried using a gridview and messing with the child aspect ratio but I am unable to make it dynamic.

I have also tried to do a Column which has Rows with expanded children. The only way I have managed to do this is by putting the column in a fixed height container and this causes the children to flex based on that container height (not the largest child).

I need to put this grid of buttons in a shrink wrapped list view.

Thank you for your time and feel free to ask questions if you need clarifications.

Comment: may be you need this:https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: They are all different sizes. I need them to all be the same size.